# Crown summoned too many octopi

Tags: candy-box-2

[image]

Is there a way to clear the octopi army without restarting the level? This exact scenario is difficult to get out of with teleport and jump.

Comment: I don't recall 100%, but doesn't your spells affect the spawned Octopi as ell?

Answer (score 1):

**Black demons** is the only spell that can kill friendly summons. You don't have it yet, but you can find the Black Magic Grimoire in the hole, which unlocks the Black demons and Obsidian wall spells.

Unfortunately, you're probably stuck without it, since you said teleport and jump are ineffective. Have you also tried to slow down time?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generally get rid of octopi without black magic, but you can, if you are in a fighting quest, teleport behind them and let enemies kill them off. After that, you will probably be better equipped taking off the crown.